# Java - экшн по закрытию окна

Tags: awt, java, классы

Есть у меня, допустим, окно JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Так вот, как бы мне повесить вызов какой-нибудь функции на его закрытие? Я знаю, что можно вызывать *addWindowListener* -

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
...
});
```

...но тогда требуется вставлять вообще все методы из *WindowListener*, сделать Override какого-то одного он не позволяет. С другой стороны, можно создать и отдельный класс для этих целей, что-нибудь типа

```
static class ClosingAction extends WindowAdapter {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
        //сделать что-то
    }
}

...

frame.addWindowListener(new ClosingAction());
```

...но тогда я никак не смогу получить доступ к локальным переменным, созданным в функции, в которой фрейм. Как быть? Чую, есть какой-то простой способ, но мозг уже не соображает)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я обычно добавлял анонимный класс, с наследованием от WindowListener(), а неиспользуемые методы не реализовывал. Как вариант - анонимный наследник WindowAdapter с заменой нужного метода, остальные, как я помню, там и так с пустой реализацией.

Comment: С *WindowAdapter()* ошибки действительно уже не выдает, но и функция почему-то не срабатывает (я меняю текст лейбла в другом фрейме). Но задача так или иначе решена, спасибо)